# Spring MongoRepository not returning id field of nested objects

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a `collection` in MongoDB, named customer, as viewed in MongoDB Compass:

[image: Data in Mongo]

When this collection is retrieved using `spring data mongo` the value of the embedded `fruits` objects' `id` is lost and shown as `null`:

```
[
  {
   "id": "605b7f97ca7b62d786bba54c",
   "fruits": [
    {
     "id": null, <<===== THIS IS NULL, WHY?
     "code": "M",
     "description": "Mango",
     "inactive": false,
     "label": null
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

What could be the cause?

**Model**

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    public String id;
    private List<MyList> fruits ;
}


public class MyList {
    private String id;
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private boolean inactive;

}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> { }
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping(path="/customers")
public @ResponseBody List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
    return customerRepository.findAll();

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: try using `@Field` annotation. From docs "A property or field without an annotation but named id maps to the _id field"

Comment: The type  of id is ObjectId in mongodb. But in spring, its String!!. And use `_id` in spring also,

Comment: @JensSchauder, yes it does. Can you please post as 'answer'?